# How to make scalafmt remove space before argument braces

Tags: scala, scalafmt

When processing function calls, `scalafmt` will remove spaces before parentheses around the arguments:

```
val res = myList.map (myFunction)
```

becomes

```
val res = myList.map(myFunction)
```

But if braces are used rather than parentheses it *adds* spaces:

```
val res = myList.map{ case x => myFunction(x) }
```

becomes

```
val res = myList.map { case x => myFunction(x) }
```

Is there a way to have `scalafmt` remove the space in front of the braces in this case and not add one?

(The spaces inside the braces are good, I just don't want the space before the opening brace)